# How to make a script that waits for user input?

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, input, subprocess

i am trying to make an application in python that will act like a command prompt, that will execute commands that I created, but I don't want it always be running.

I want to have a script run on startup that will be hidden and on an infinite loop, that will listen if I pressed a certain hotkey. Of that is true then it just runs a different python program
So I searched a bit and I thought I should make a different application that will be hidden from the user and when the hotkeys `"ctrl+alt+shift+;"` are detected to be pressed then the actual prompt runs

I tried adding a python script in the startup folder of windows to run on startup and be hidden and only run the prompt when the hotkey is detected.

But that didn't work because when the prompt runner is hidden then the actual prompt is also hidden.

This is the script that runs "prompt"

```py
import subprocess, keyboard, time

def start_prompt():
    SW_HIDE = 0
    info = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    info.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    subprocess.Popen(r'PATH_HERE', startupinfo=info)

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+alt+shift+;"):
        start_prompt()
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

So I need to create a script that will run on startup and start listening if the hotkey `"ctrl+alt+shift+;"` is pressed, and when that happens it runs a different python script I wrote.

I don't think the code of the prompt is needed because it is probably not of use.

Comment: You can probably do this on Window using the `msvcrt` module's [Console I/O](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html#console-i-o) functions (i.e. `kbhit()` and `getch()`). I recently learned of a third-party module named [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) that could also be used.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at `msvcrt`